# Should null value in a field be treated differently from the field absent in schema design for xml and/or json?

Tags: json, xml, xsd, schema, nosql

Should null value in a field be treated differently from the field absent in schema design for xml and/or json? How to do that?

I can see current implementations do not separate null value in a field with this field absent.
If this is the case, I must have another field "hasXXXX" field to confirm null existence of this field. Is this good design for NoSQL?

For my use case, it do have business value for the existence of this field, even it's null or not.

Basically, this is to say: I need to the the difference between:

- He don't have any "property".
- I don't know that he have "property" or not.

Comment: If it is of business value to know the difference, then yes, it should be treated differently. That sounds like a business question.

Comment: @lit Yes, from business, it's different. How to design this with one field or two fields. Can one field enough for this business situation?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good vehicle for design discussions. This is a topic that has been discussed in the information management research literature for 50 years, without definitive conclusions. There is no way the simple Q&A format of StackOverflow can add any useful insights; you'll just get some random opinions, many of them from people who haven't studied that literature.

Answer (score 1):

You have the opportunity to associate different semantics with an absent attribute/property and an attribute/property whose value is empty.

Whether you *should or not* and what those two possibilities should represent depend upon your design goals and those of the producers and consumers of your data.

One design decision would be to designate that an absent attribute represents a lack of knowledge or assertion of a value and that an empty value represents knowledge or assertion that the value is actually empty.

[Ah, and you just edited the question to state that your business case does have a need to represent exactly those two possibilities, so I would say that, yes, your approach is very reasonable.]

Comment: Should I use two fields: XXXX, haveXXXX for this requirement? It seems not easy to handle the difference between null value and absent field with current library, like [avro](https://avro.apache.org/).

Comment: Seems viable, albeit redundant, if your system/library isn't supporting the absence-means-unknown approach.